# Installing a third party setup as part of my application's installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

I'm trying to configure a project in Visual Studio 2015 for building an installer for my application. To this end, I've installed [Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects).

My application installation process includes installing some third party setup. I managed to get my hands on some other project doing the same, so when the main application is about to install, at the end, it will start the other third party setup and wait for it to end before the whole process is reported as completed.

In the sample project I've found, I can see that there's a section called `CustomAction` (I've opened the .vdproj with a text editor). This section has some instructions in it like this:

```
"CustomAction"
{
    "{4AA51A2D-7D85-4A59-BA75-B0809FC8B380}:_8A3405B1C66648A68EE1E271E3242DB9"
    {
    "Name" = "8:Third_Party_Setup.exe"
    "Condition" = "8:"
    "Object" = "8:_ECA68EE68CB845BBAF49181F67A13229"
    "FileType" = "3:2"
    "InstallAction" = "3:1"
    "Arguments" = "8:/Install"
    "EntryPoint" = "8:"
    "Sequence" = "3:1"
    "Identifier" = "8:_4C0498BC_1D15_483F_B061_5801E7ABDC85"
    "InstallerClass" = "11:FALSE"
    "CustomActionData" = "8:"
    }
}
```

Even though I'm not sure but I think this is what results in running the third party setup. In the setup project that I've created, the same section exists but it's empty. And I can't find any menu in Visual Studio how to create it. Of course, I can fill that part up using a text editor but I would rather find the right way of doing so.

So my question is; how can I include a third part setup as part of my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, I was missing a whole side to Installer template which you can get to by right clicking on the project -> view:

[image]

And here's a good article on how to use these features:

[Create custom dialogs for an Setup project in Visual Studio 2015](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1028052/Create-custom-dialogs-for-an-Setup-project-in-Visu)